# Not receiving notifications of other answers or comments

Tags: support, notifications

I recently have an issue with comments and other answers notifications in browser.
If I navigate to the question itself I can see other comments and/or answers to the same question I answered:

[image]

But in the header, I don't see them:
[image]

Any idea why is that happening?

Comment: You'll only get notifications of comments where you are specifically notified, via the `@username` syntax, or that are on your questions or answers. Likewise, you'll only get answer notifications on your own questions.

Comment: @Kendra thanks, got it :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're not *supposed* to get notifications of other answers to a question you've answered, or comments that are not posted to your own answer or that @ reply to you.